# WinAppDriver and SyncFusion GridGroupingControl

Tags: syncfusion, winappdriver

I am trying to use WinAppDriver to automate reading/writing to a SyncFusion control: GridGroupingCOntrol.
The UIRecorder tool is not able to extract xpaths for elements inside the control, nor can winappdriver see them. Does anyone know a workaround or how to extract data from the cells of such a control?

Answer (score 0):

We have checked the reported query  ”To automate read/write on syncfusion controls” at our end. As per the current implementation, we do not have the support to automate read/write using WinAppDriver. For this query already we have logged a feature request. We will implement this feature in any of our upcoming releases.